# When I change one instance of a GregorianCalendar the other instance changes aswell

Tags: java, time, gregorian-calendar

```
final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance() ;
    GregorianCalendar time = new GregorianCalendar();
    GregorianCalendar limit = time;
    limit.add(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);

    String timeForm = dateFormat.format(time.getTime());
    String limitForm = dateFormat.format(limit.getTime());
    System.out.println(timeForm);
    System.out.println(limitForm);
```

The output should be the time "now" followed by the time after 4 hours.

When it prints out, both timeForm and limitForm display the time after 4 hours. Why is that?

Comment: There's only one instance there. A variable is not an instance, it's a reference to one. `GeorgianCalendar limit = time;` does not create a new instance of `GeorgianCalendar`, it just tells `limit` to reference the same object that `time` is referencing.

Answer (score 1):

You set the second calendar equal to the first instead of creating a second instance. So when you change the instance it affects both variables. If you make `limit = new GregorianCalendar();` the output will show 2 different values

Answer (score 1):

You want to step back and read how Java is dealing with "reference types".

In other words: anything in Java that is some sort of Object (like GregorianCalendar objects) is identified via a **reference**.

And when you make an assignment like

```
limit = time;
```

then you are **not** creating another Object. You just have to two variables, time and limit, that both "point" to the very same object.

Thus when you use one variable and make a status-changing change on the reference object; of course the other variable "sees" those changes, too.